# Wrong results in elasticsearch complex boolean query over nested objects

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a recipients index containing a nested activity object which stores event types and campaign ids.

Here is an example:

```
{
    email: 'm1@example.com',
    userId: 'user-id'
    listId: 'list-id'
    campaignActivity: [
       { event: 'received', campaignId: 'c1', timestamp: 1 },
       { event: 'received', campaignId: 'c3', timestamp: 3 }
    ]
}
```

Here is my current mapping:

```
{
  "recipients_index_test": {
    "mappings": {
      "recipients": {
        "properties": {
          "campaignActivity": {
            "type": "nested",
            "properties": {
              "campaignId": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                  "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                  }
                }
              },
              "event": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                  "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                  }
                }
              },
              "timestamp": {
                "type": "long"
              }
            }
          },
          "email": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "id": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "listId": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "userId": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the sample data:

```
{
  email: 'nm1@example.com',
  userId: 'user-id',
  listId: 'list-id',
  campaignActivity: [
    { event: 'received', campaignId: 'c1', timestamp: 1 },
    { event: 'received', campaignId: 'c2', timestamp: 2 },
    { event: 'received', campaignId: 'c3', timestamp: 3 },
    { event: 'received', campaignId: 'c4', timestamp: 4 }
  ]
},
{
  email: 'nm2@example.com',
  userId: 'user-id',
  listId: 'list-id',
  campaignActivity: [
    { event: 'received', campaignId: 'c1', timestamp: 1 }
  ]
},
{
  email: 'm1@example.com',
  userId: 'user-id',
  listId: 'list-id',
  campaignActivity: []
},
{
  email: 'm2@example.com',
  userId: 'user-id',
  listId: 'list-id',
  campaignActivity: [
    { event: 'received', campaignId: 'c1', timestamp: 1 },
    { event: 'received', campaignId: 'c3', timestamp: 3 }
  ]
},
{
  email: 'm3@example.com',
  userId: 'user-id',
  listId: 'list-id',
  campaignActivity: [
    { event: 'received', campaignId: 'c2', timestamp: 2 },
    { event: 'received', campaignId: 'c3', timestamp: 3 }
  ]
}
```

I want to get recipients who didn't receive some of c2, c3 or c4 campaigns (by excluding recipients who received all campaigns c2, c3 and c4) This is what I've been trying without luck:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must_not": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "campaignActivity",
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "filter": [
                  {
                    "term": {
                      "campaignActivity.campaignId.keyword": "c4"
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "term": {
                      "campaignActivity.event.keyword": "received"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "campaignActivity",
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "filter": [
                  {
                    "term": {
                      "campaignActivity.campaignId.keyword": "c3"
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "term": {
                      "campaignActivity.event.keyword": "received"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "campaignActivity",
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "filter": [
                  {
                    "term": {
                      "campaignActivity.campaignId.keyword": "c2"
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "term": {
                      "campaignActivity.event.keyword": "received"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "from": 0,
  "size": 10
}
```

Above query returns nm2@example.com and m1@example.com but I'm looking for a result with m1@example.com, m2@example.com, and m3@example.com

What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE 1:**

This is the closest I've gotten so far:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "campaignActivity",
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "filter": [
                  {
                    "term": {
                      "campaignActivity.event.keyword": "received"
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "terms": {
                      "campaignActivity.campaignId.keyword": [
                        "c4",
                        "c3",
                        "c2"
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "should": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "campaignActivity",
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "must_not": [
                  {
                    "term": {
                      "campaignActivity.campaignId.keyword": "c4"
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "term": {
                      "campaignActivity.event.keyword": "received"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "campaignActivity",
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "must_not": [
                  {
                    "term": {
                      "campaignActivity.campaignId.keyword": "c3"
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "term": {
                      "campaignActivity.event.keyword": "received"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "campaignActivity",
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "must_not": [
                  {
                    "term": {
                      "campaignActivity.campaignId.keyword": "c2"
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "term": {
                      "campaignActivity.event.keyword": "received"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "from": 0,
  "size": 10
}
```

But it still returns nm1@example.com which shouldn't be part of the result because it received all of the campaigns (c2,c3,c4) and is missing m1@example.com.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it working with this query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "bool": {
                  "must_not": [
                    {
                      "nested": {
                        "path": "campaignActivity",
                        "query": {
                          "bool": {
                            "filter": {
                              "exists": {
                                "field": "campaignActivity"
                              }
                            }
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              },
              {
                //match c2
              },
              {
                //match c3
              },
              {
                //match c4
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "must_not": [
              {
                "bool": {
                  "must": [
                    {
                      //match c2
                    },
                    {
                      //match c3
                    },
                    {
                      //match c4
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I hope it will be helpful for someone in the future.